# bash dialog inputbox with variable entered

Tags: bash, variables, dialog, inputbox

I'm struggling with this code:

```
komanda=$(dialog --title "COMMAND" --backtitle "ENTER COMMAND: "
--inputbox "" 8 180 2>&1 >/dev/tty) 
if [ $? == 0 ]   then
    for  ((j=0;j<$tlen;j++))
      do
      shopnum=${selectedRPODS[j]}
      $komanda #executing the entered comand with variables.
    done
fi
```

When I enter a variable in the inputbox, the parameter is passed on as a string. Variables are not working when execute at $komanda

Example input text:

```
ping $shopnum
```

returns always:

```
ping: unknown host $shopnum
```

I wanted to have the variable as destination for the ping. I know its something I'm doing wrong with the STDOUT but I can't find the right way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameter expansions are not recursive. If you enter `ping $shopnum`, then `$komanda` expands to the literal text `ping $shopnum`, not `ping 3` or whatever value was assigned to `shopnum`.

In this case, since your intention is to execute arbitrary shell code, you would use `eval`:

```
eval "$komanda"
```

However, it would be better to rethink your design so that the user doesn't need to know what variable names exist in the code.

Comment: Thanks that has worked. I was so focused on the STDOUT and dialog I didn't even think of this.